# How to call randomly generate numbers in Android java app?

Tags: java, android

Ok here's the deal, I've seen a similar question but not exactly what i was looking for. Basically I want to create an app that randomly chooses a given set of numbers (9-12 numbers) like a credit card generator from digits 0-9. And have that app prefixed and suffixed with letters of my choice, then call the results automatically in a background process on my phone.

Comment: Lovely.  So what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

So basically you need two things. Generating random numbers and calling a number in Android.

For the first problem you can find [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=62) some good examples. For the second problem you can find [here](http://www.androiddevelopment.org/2008/10/21/android-development-demo-dialanumber-how-to-write-your-own-very-first-android-program-made-simple/) a complete tutorial that guides you through all necessary steps.

With these two hints you should be able to solve your problem. If not, I would recommend to post the code you tried so far and ask a more narrowed down question.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is important to note: the Random in Android, or just coding in general, its based off of the millisecond that the app requests the random number. What I would do in my apps is have it call a Random number generator, then use the value it creates to run through a switch with values scattered across the switch statements. It makes it a little more random.
I only say this because I am not sure if you need a TRUELY random number of if the way the system does it is good enough.